# Create a random number multiple times in JS

Tags: javascript, random

I want to generate a random number in Javascript 6 times. I've got the random variable declared and properly functioning. I just need to replicate it six times without logging it six separate times.

`const randRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 10;`

How would I go about this?

Comment: The same way you'd do _anything_ multiple times - the keyword to look for in tutorials is a "loop".

Comment: `Array(6).fill(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 10)` ?

Comment: @customcommander that's actually wrong. `fill()` makes all elements the same.

Comment: _"I just need to replicate it six times without logging it six separate times."_: what does this mean? What does your function look like? Where are you logging anything?

Comment: @RoboRobok I know but it's not clear whether OP wants that same random number 6 times or not. So ‍♂️

Comment: If you need exactly 6 random numbers you may as well just do `[0,0,0,0,0,0].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 10)`

Comment: I'm realizing I worded this question improperly. I would like to have 6 different randomly generated numbers. I'm still very new to javascript programming and still grasping the functionality of loops and arrays. I understand how to generate the random number, but properly creating the loop was where I was struggling. One of the answers provided a good answer to my problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way of doing this is using for loop

```js
let randomNumbers = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  randomNumbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 10);
}
```

You can also do something like this

```js
let randomNumbers = new Array(6).fill(0).map((v) => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a random number in Javascript, the `math.random()` function is used. JavaScript `math.random()` generates a random decimal value between 0 and 1.

`const random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); console.log(random_num);`

As you can see,In the above example, I used the Math.floor() function to round our random number up to become a random integer, used “* 10” to generate a number between “1” and “10”.

If you need generate a number ( 1 to 100 ) you can multiply generated number by 100  and so on “* maxNumberHer”.

**Random Number Between Two Values**
`Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)`
Between 900 to 1000

`const generateRandomNum = (min, max) =>  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)   console.log(generateRandomNum(900, 1000))`

**about Repeat 6 times**
You can use for loop

`for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) { console.log(generateRandomNum(900, 1000)); }`